# how to add custom attribute in catalog/category in magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

how to add custom attribute in catalog/category in admin general tab which will display only on specific store not for all.

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::ENTITY, 
'banner_img1',

 array(
    'group'             => 'General',
    'type'              => 'text',
    'label'             => 'Door Banner Image1',
    'visible'           => true,
    'required'          => false,
    'visible_on_front'  => false,
    'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
));

$installer->endSetup();`
```

but above code create attribute in all store view i want to show only for 1 store

Answer (score 0):

Magento attributes do not work that way. Store scope means that attribute can have different value for each store view, but you can't have it exist for one and not for other.

Even tho there's no way to add an attribute only for one store view, you can upload the image only for particular store view and add the check in your theme which will output the attribute only if it's present.